# Email template 'custom_mail_template' is not defined

Tags: magento2, email-templates, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta

I'm trying to send mail from my custom module. For this I have created `system.xml` file, but it's returning error.

**Error:**

> Email template 'custom_mail_template' is not defined.

**my code is:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custom" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
            <label>custom mail</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="custom" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>custom mail</label>
            <tab>custom</tab>
            <resource>Learning_Custom::config_custom</resource>
            <group id="mail" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Custom</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enabled</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Template</label>
                    <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Any suggestions will appreciate.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need create file `email_templates.xml` in `etc` folder with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
       <template id="custom_mail_template" label=" Your Custom Label" file="yourfile.html" type="html" module="Vendor_YourModule" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**This file using declare template have id `custom_mail_template` in Configuration with path of template file you want use.**

After, you create template email file `yourfile.html` in path `Vendor/YourModule/view/frontend/email/yourfile.html`

I hope it help for you.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: So template id in email_templates.xml should match the path in system.xml separated by underscores. Woah Magennnnntooooo!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I face the same problem when I use a custom email template and its resolved by the following changes.

If you check your system.xml file you can find that you path for system config for email template is created based upon that. In simple terms, email template-id is created upon sectionid_groupid_fieldid.

Here it is `custom_mail_template`.

Comment: This. And it looks like that even if you have a `config.xml` defining the defaults for the config path set in `system.xml`, that default must still be equal to the config path itself, but delimited with underscores (_) instead of slashes (/). Otherwise, you get the error.

Answer (score -2):

If everything looks correct and still getting this error, please try running below commands and check. It worked for me.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```